# Read list of dicts as single column pandas while keeping comma separator

Tags: python, pandas

I have a string

```
'1,10,aux,rank,[{"id": "1"}, {"id": "2"}, {"id": "3"}, {"id": "4"}]'
```

Which 5th element is generated from the code:

```
json.dumps([
                    {"id": "1"},
                    {"id": "2"},
                    {"id": "3"},
                    {"id": "4"},
                ])
```

I would like to read with pandas.

My current code is

```
TESTDATA = StringIO('1,10,aux,rank,[{"id": "1"}, {"id": "2"}, {"id": "3"}, {"id": "4"}]'
)

df = pd.read_csv(TESTDATA, names=["column1", "column2", "column3", "column4", "column5"],
                 header=None, usecols=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
df
```

but doesnt read the column5 correctly as is a list of dictionaries. the output is

```
    column1 column2 column3 column4 column5
0   1   10  aux rank    [{"id": "1"}
```

How can I correctly read column5 as [{"id": "1"}, {"id": "2"}, {"id": "3"}, {"id": "4"}] while keeping a comma separated csv? I know i could use other separators in order not to break the strings, but it isn't an option.

Ideal output would be:

```
    column1 column2 column3 column4 column5
0   1   10  aux rank    [{"id": "1"}, {"id": "2"}, {"id": "3"}, {"id": "4"}]
```

Comment: How do you get this string? Will there be break line in this string?

Comment: there wont be a break line, it comes from dumping a str in json format. I'll update the original post with it

Comment: If it's you generate this string, you can use an operator instead of comma like semicolon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use a normal csv reader here to format the data how you want it, then feed it to the `DataFrame` constructor:

```py
import csv
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

TESTDATA = StringIO('1,10,aux,rank,[{"item_id": "1"}, {"item_id": "2"}, {"item_id": "3"}, {"item_id": "4"}]'
)

reader = csv.reader(TESTDATA)

columns = [f'column{i}' for i in range(1, 6)]

# unpack all of the columns, but group the list ones together
a, b, c, d, *e = next(reader)

# put the commas back into your json column
e = ','.join(e)

data = [dict(zip(columns, (a, b, c, d, e)))]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df
  column1 column2 column3 column4                                            column5
0       1      10     aux    rank  [{"item_id": "1"}, {"item_id": "2"}, {"item_id...
```

Or, to put it into a loop for the whole file:

```py
with open('yourfile.csv', newline='') as fh:
    data = []
    reader = csv.reader(fh)
    columns = [f'column{i}' for i in range(1, 6)]

    for a, b, c, d, *e in reader:
        e = ','.join(e)
        data.append(dict(zip(columns, (a, b, c, d, e))))


df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

## Edit

To avoid the overhead of building a list for larger datasets, you could have `pd.DataFrame` consume a generator here:

```py
def format_data(file):
    with open(file, newline='') as fh:
        reader = csv.reader(fh)
        columns = [f'column{i}' for i in range(1, 6)]
    
        for a, b, c, d, *e in reader:
            e = ','.join(e)
            yield dict(zip(columns, (a, b, c, d, e)))


df = pd.DataFrame(format_data('myfile.csv'))
```

Comment: that seems to add a lot of overhead prior to the pd read, let me benchmark its time when running against bigger strings.

Comment: There's no `pd.read` here, instead, I'm reading directly from the csv file itself. The only overhead you might consider is the construction of the list itself, but you could have it consume a generator instead if you wanted to